# Call different functions when clicking on a map vs. clicking on a polygon in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, polygon, javascript

I have a `map` and I add a `featureGroup` to it. Then, I add some `polygon`s to the `featureGroup`.
Now I want something to happen, when a `polygon` in `featureGroup` is clicked and something else to happen when a place on `the` map outside of the `featureGroup` to be clicked. This is what I have done:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([52.51616, 13.31339], 11);
var featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

map.on('click',function(e) {
        console.log('clicked on map');
});
    
featureGroup.on('click',function(e) {
        console.log('clicked on polygon');
});
```

But when I click on a `polygon` of `featureGroup`, the consolereads

> clicked on polygon
> clicked on map

When I click on the `map` (outside of a `polygon`):

> clicked on map

I want only the `featureGroup`'s listener to be fired, when clicked on a member of that group, not the `map`'s listener.

I use Leaflet 1.6.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to prevent propagation of `click` event once you catch it in `featureGroup` layer. Leaflet has handy method `L.DomEvent.stopPropagation` just for that (see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#domevent).

In your case code would look something like that:

```
featureGroup.on('click',function(e) {
  console.log('clicked on polygon');
  L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
});
```